# How to index the unique value count in numpy?

Tags: numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

If the array is `np.array([1, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 6, 3])`, then I want to get array like this; `np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2])`. Is there any numpy options? Or do I have to make new function?

Comment: Yea. But I got a new error.

Comment: this is my data: [144 144 144 144 143 143 143  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  93]
and this is what I got: [3 2 1 0 2 1 0 9 0 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 8]

I want to get data like this: [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1 ...]

Comment: @mozway. Nice find. The dupe hammer is strong today, but actually good questions for the most part